# Alternating sum of powers

Tags: nt.number-theory

Fix a positive integer $k$.  Is it true that for large enough $n$ there exist signs such that $$\pm 1^k\pm 2 ^k\pm \dots \pm n^k=(n(n+1)/2\,  \text{mod}\,  2)? $$

It is not hard to show that such sums may be made bounded (since $2^{k+1}$ consecutive signs may be chosen so that the contribution of corresponding summands equals to 0.) But I do not see immediate reasons why it can not be made so ultimately small.

Comment: this is related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149625/finding-the-min-of-m-such-that-k-pm-1n-pm-2n-pm-3n-pm-cdots-pm-mn?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly of course, thank you

Comment: The property you mentioned immediately generalizes to any polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $k$ or less: one can make $\pm P(1)\pm P(2)\pm\dots P(2^{k+1}-1)=0$. This could be useful, if conveniently applied to sequences related to $1^k,2^k,\dots$

Comment: For what it's worth, if the statement is true for some $K:=2^{k+1}$ consecutive values of $n$, then it is true also for all larger values; this is because, if $\tau_1,\dotsc,\tau_K$ are the first $K$ elements of the Thue-Morse sequence, then $\tau_ln^k+\tau_2(n-1)^k+\dotsb+\tau_K(n-(K-1))^k=0$.

Comment: Maybe this https://mathoverflow.net/a/248427 can get you part of the way there.  Gerhard "Can Contribute Some Gas Money" Paseman, 2018.03.31.

Comment: Have you tried the circle method? If yes, what was the difficulty? (I haven't tried myself yet, but I surmise you are as good as I in such matters, so I decided to ask before duplicating the effort).

Comment: @fedja I have not tried seriously, but on the first glance there are too many multiples in the product $f(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n (z^{j^k}+z^{-j^k})$ to control of the integral of $f(z)$ or $f(z)/z$ over a unit circle. Or which variant of the circle method do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many multiples (factors?)"? Obviously, there are two special neighborhoods: that of $1$ and that of $-1$, but at the first glance it looks like *there is nothing else to worry about* and the function is either even, or odd, so the influences of these two neighborhoods just add up, if the parity is chosen correctly. OK, let me try myself and see what I can squeeze of it :-)

Comment: It works without any trouble and, indeed, everything outside $n^{-k}$-neighborhoods of $1$ and $-1$ is negligible in the uniform norm (just some boring casework). No time for posting now but I'll try to do it later unless somebody beats me to it.